# Firebase Database Get Specific Values of Child Using Map

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Problem: I am creating an Android app that allows users to book desks and have run into issues with how to retrieve data from the Firebase realtime database child values.

My aim from my code: I want to get the userId and desk number for all entries under all users so I can set the desks that have been booked to have a specific image display on my `RecyclerView` for my desk selection page.

My current code: My Firebase database is set up for the bookings as follows:

```html
{
  "bookings" : {
    "LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1" : {
      "-L9b5LpjYz8yDwXkPUoh" : {
        "booked" : true,
        "date" : "2018/4/19",
        "desk" : "18",
        "userId" : "LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1"
      },
      "-L9b5iJGeQ_58geFUkZa" : {
        "booked" : true,
        "date" : "2018/4/13",
        "desk" : "14",
        "userId" : "LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1"
      },
      "-L9b7tcd8kJJQ-q_7UZo" : {
        "booked" : true,
        "date" : "2018/4/10",
        "desk" : "6",
        "userId" : "LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1"
      },
      "-L9bCktGaluOj7Rw-7_6" : {
        "booked" : true,
        "date" : "2018/4/20",
        "desk" : "6",
        "userId" : "LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1"
      }
    }
  }
```

With the children: `userID`, a unique push id and then the booking details. I am trying to retrieve the desk number and user Id for each entry under the unique push Id however I cannot figure out how to get the values.

I have a database reference to the bookings node. I have a single value event listener for the database reference. In the `onDataChange` method I have added a method passing in a map and the value of the datasnapshot.

I can see that there is only one key (the userId and the values are all the children of the userId.

I have tried to create a map and get the desk values from the data snapshot but my array size is only 1 as it seems to be just checking the key and not the values. I have tried changing the database reference to child("bookings").child(") to try and reference the userId but it's returning the same thing.

I also tried to get the value of the datasnapshot.child("").getValue(); but it's returning the same as datasnapshot.getValue();. Checking datasnapshot.getChildren(); shows just 1.

```js
 //Connection to the database, gets a reference to the root of the Firebase JSON tree
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //Access to the child location
    DatabaseReference mDB = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("bookings");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_desk);

        mDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null)
                {
                    getDeskAndUser((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());

                    Log.e(TAG, "Datasnapshot get value: "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Datasnapshot is null");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
            }
        });
private void getDeskAndUser(Map<String,Object> bookings)
    {

        ArrayList<String> deskNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        //iterate through each booking, ignoring their UID
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> desk : bookings.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("key=" + desk.getKey() + ", value=" + desk.getValue());

            //Get user map
            Map singleUserDesk = (Map) desk.getValue();
            System.out.println(singleUserDesk);
            //Get desk field and append to list
            deskNumbers.add((String) singleUserDesk.get("desk"));

        }
        ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> userId : bookings.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("key=" + userId.getKey() + ", value=" + userId.getValue());

            //Get user map
            Map singleUserDesk = (Map) userId.getValue();
            //Get desk field and append to list
            users.add((String) singleUserDesk.get("userId"));

        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Array size is " + bookings.size());
        // Create an ArrayList of BookingDetails objects
        ArrayList<BookingDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bookings.size(); i++)
        {
            details.add(new BookingDetails());
            Log.e(TAG, "Contents of the array list" + details.toString());

        }
    }
```

My BookingDetails object to create bookings in database

```js
public class BookingDetails {
  private static final String TAG = "BookingDetails";
  private String userId;
  private String key;
  private String desk;
  private String date;
  private boolean booked;

  public BookingDetails() {}

  public BookingDetails(String userId, String key, String desk, String date, boolean booked) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.key = key;
    this.desk = desk;
    this.date = date;
    this.booked = booked;

  }

  public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }

  public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public String getDesk() {
    return desk;
  }

  public String getDate() {
    return date;
  }

  public void setDesk(String desk) {
    this.desk = desk;
  }

  public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
  public boolean isBooked() {
    return booked;
  }

  public void setBooked(boolean booked) {
    this.booked = booked;
  }
}
```

And my confirmBooking method to set the data in the database

```js
public void confirm(View view) {
  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
  if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
    String userId = user.getUid();
    writeNewBooking(userId, null, mDeskNum, mDateSelected, true);

    Intent confirm = new Intent(this, MyBookingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(confirm);

  } else {
    // No user is signed in
    Log.e(TAG, "No user is signed in!");
  }
}

private void writeNewBooking(String userId, String key, String desk, String date, Boolean booked) {
  DatabaseReference postsRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("bookings").child(userId);
  DatabaseReference newPostRef = postsRef.push();
  newPostRef.setValue(new BookingDetails(userId, key, desk, date, booked));
  newPostRef.getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("bookings").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String desk = ds.child("desk").getValue(String.class);
            String userId = ds.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", desk + " / " + userId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which the `uid` for the corresponding logged in user is `LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1`.

The output will be:

```
18 / LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1
14 / LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1
6 / LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1
6 / LppMaD3QPBWgMucW8k7mno7tPNu1
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Alex, however my question is how to get the bookings for all users not just the current user - my JSON above is a bad example as I only had one user  with bookings in the database at that point. I'm not sure without having the uid for the other users how to access the child data

Comment: Just loop through the users in the exact same way, using getChildren() method. Does it work?

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?

Comment: I had to do a nested for loop as the child of bookings > uid is the unique push code. once I looped throught the child of the child I was able to get the keys and values I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I accepted it there, thank you for the help!