# print map data using key from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

see results in image but i need only value of this map

```
void getData() async{
    //print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    setState(() async {
      dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data').child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
      dbsnapshot = await dbref.get();
     print(dbsnapshot.value);
     //print(dbsnapshot.value['email'].toString()); //not working

      // print(dbsnapshot.child('firtname').toString());//not working
    });
  }
```

in need results like this
***kha mu     m,tayyaba3@gmail.com***

```
//print(dbsnapshot.value['email'].toString()); //not working
    
          // print(dbsnapshot.child('firtname').toString());//not working


 final result = dbsnapshot.value.values.join(" ");
    print(result); // not working
```

i try this but its not working

Comment: check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68304466/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748487/18265638) which might help